# Laravel whereIn with a where clause on each array item

Tags: php, arrays, laravel, where-in

Say I have a user object (which belongsToMany groups) and I'm doing a whereIn with an array of their respected ids like so:

```
whereIn('user_id', $group->users->modelKeys())
```

I need to, however, set a condition where I only pull data from each array item based on a condition of the group_user pivot table, "created_at" (which is basically a timestamp of when that user was added to the group).

So I need something like this:

```
whereIn('user_id', $group->users->modelKeys())->whereRaw('visits.created_at > group_user.created_at')
```

That doesn't work though because it's not doing the whereRaw for each array item but it's doing it once for the query as a whole. I might need to do something like a nested whereIn but not sure if that'll solve it either. Thoughts?

My full query as it is now:

```
     $ids = $group->users->modelKeys();

     return DB::table('visits')->whereIn('user_id', function($query) use ($ids) {
        $query->select('user_id')->from('group_user')->whereIn('group_user.user_id', $ids)->whereRaw('visits.created_at > group_user.created_at');
    })->sum("views");
```

Ok got it to work using nested loops instead:

```
    $visits = DB::table('visits')->whereIn('user_id', $group->users->modelKeys())->get();

    $sum = 0;

    foreach($group->users as $user) {

        foreach($visits as $visit) {

            if($visit->user_id == $user->id) {

                if($visit->created_at >= $user->pivot->created_at) {
                    $sum += $visit->views;
                }
            }
        }

    }

    return $sum;
```

Would still like to see if it's possible to do it in a single query, no array looping.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Solved it! The foreach loop approach was making calls take waaaay too long. Some queries had over 100k records returning (that's a lot to loop through) causing the server to hang up. The answer is in part a big help from Dharmesh Patel with his 3rd edit approach. The only thing I had to do differently was add a where clause for the group_id.

Here's the final query (returns that 100k results query in milliseconds)

```
    //Eager loading. Has overhead for large queries
    //$ids = $group->users->modelKeys();

    //No eager loading. More efficient
    $ids = DB::table('group_user')->where('group_id', $group->id)->lists('user_id');

    return DB::table('visits')->join('group_user', function ($query) use ($ids) {
        $query->on('visits.user_id', '=', 'group_user.user_id')->on('visits.created_at', '>=', 'group_user.created_at');
    })->whereIn('group_user.user_id', $ids)->where('group_id', $group->id)->sum('views');
```

Comment: Made it even more efficient by not using eager loading to retrieve the user_ids (eager loading has overhead for large queries). Instead I'm doing this:

    `$ids = DB::table('group_user')->where('group_id', $group->id)->lists('user_id');` Updated my answer with this.

Answer (score 1):

Have you considered using a `foreach`?

```
$users = whereIn('user_id', $group->users->modelKeys());

foreach ($users as $user) {
  // do your comparison here
}
```

Comment: I was hoping to avoid that as it could lead to excessive multiple queries

Comment: I think you'll find that it does not. The comparisons should be done in php.

Comment: Ok you're right. If I do a couple nested loops with a couple nested if statements I can populate my return array. Was hoping to see if there is a way to do it with just one single query though...

Answer (score 1):

I guess you need to use JOINS for this query, following code may take you in right direction:

```
$ids = $group->users->modelKeys();

return DB::table('visits')->join('group_user', function ($query) use ($ids) {
    $query->on('visits.user_id', '=', 'group_user.user_id')
        ->whereIn('group_user.user_id', $ids)
        ->whereRaw('visits.created_at > group_user.created_at');
})->sum("views");
```

**EDIT**

```
$ids = $group->users->modelKeys();

return DB::table('visits')->join('group_user', function ($query) use ($ids) {
    $query->on('visits.user_id', '=', 'group_user.user_id');
})->whereIn('group_user.user_id', $ids)
   ->whereRaw('visits.created_at > group_user.created_at')->sum("views");
```

**EDIT**

$ids = $group->users->modelKeys();

```
return DB::table('visits')->join('group_user', function ($query) use ($ids) {
    $query->on('visits.user_id', '=', 'group_user.id') // group_user.id from group_user.user_id as per the loop
          ->on('visits.created_at', '>=', 'group_user.created_at');
})->whereIn('group_user.user_id', $ids)
   ->sum("views");
```

Comment: This returns an error: Undefined method: JoinClause::whereIn()

Comment: Thanks but this is doing some weird stuff. It's not returning the data correctly and I think it's because it's not doing the whereRaw on each of the ids. Also your query no longer needs the join to be like that with the "use($ids)" as that's happening outside of the join now. I updated my question showing the nested arrays I'm using now to make it work.  But I'd still like to find a proper query if possible.

Comment: I tested the query and I think it should work, the difference I see in your query and loop is that in query you are comparing dates with `>` where as in loop you are using `>=`. may be changing that in query will produce correct result.

Comment: No >= isn't the reason. The chances of the dates being equal to the millisecond are incredibly slim. Still using >= in both solutions my array solution is returning different (and correct) results than your query. I do appreciate your help btw.

Comment: noticed one more think that you are comparing `group_user.id` in loop instead of `group_user.user_id` as in query, try the new edited query

Comment: No I only need the user.id in my loop for that if statement so i know the visit belongs to that user.  The group_user is my relational pivot table which has a user_id, group_id, and created_at. Returning group_user.id doesn't return the user_id but just the primary index of that relation.